# SQL DB2 DECIMAL Function formatting

Tags: sql, function, formatting, db2, decimal

I have a small question about the DECIMAL Function in DB2.

For example:
DECIMAL((AVG)FLOAT(AGE))3,1)

I don't find in the internet for what the 3 and the 1 is standing for. I suppose 1 is the position after decimal point. But I don't know for what the 3 is standing for?

Comment: I would think you'd want your syntax to be `DECIMAL(AVG(FLOAT(AGE)),3,1)`

Comment: Did it not occur to you that the answer to your question could be found in the product documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter is the precision, and the third parameter is the scale.

The precision 3 means that the number can have up to three digits, and the scale 1 means that it has one position after the decimal point.

Source: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000791.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-3-2-42

Answer (score 1):

You can find the syntax of the DECIMAL function quite easily using the DB2 for z/OS Knowledge Center. Here's a link with all the information you could wish for about the DECIMAL function:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/com.ibm.db2z11.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_decimal.dita